# How to set Doctrine 1.2 ATTR_CASCADE_SAVES off in databases.yml?

Tags: database, symfony1, doctrine, cascade

I'm using Symfony 1.4 with Doctrine 1.2 and I've got the following databases.yml:

```
all:
  doctrine:
    class: sfDoctrineDatabase
    param:
      dsn:      xxxxx
      username: xxxxx
      password: xxxxx
      attributes:
         cascade_saves: false
```

I was under the impression that using the above would set `ATTR_CASCADE_SAVES` in Doctrine to false, but having run into some issues with freeing objects, I'm noticing that it actually remains `true`.

Var_dumping the following in any action file:

```
Doctrine_Manager::getInstance()->getAttribute(Doctrine::ATTR_CASCADE_SAVES);
```

... gives me `(bool)true`. Explicity setting it to false with `setAttribute()` fixes it, but I don't want to call this in several places in my code. Incidentally, setting it to `false` fixes the problems I'm having with freeing certain objects after saving.

Can anyone advise me on the correct databases.yml syntax for disabling cascading saves, or am I looking at this wrong somewhow? I can't seem to find anything useful via Google.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks correct to me - but I do things a slightly different way .... Create a new function in your `config/ProjectConfiguration.class.php` file  ->

```
public function configureDoctrineConnectionDoctrine(Doctrine_Connection $connection)
{
  $connection->setAttribute('CASCADE_SAVES', false);
}
```

you will need to change the function name to match your connection name ... (just then end "Doctrine" part)

Comment: Thanks - accepting in the absence of any other answers, although it's no exactly what I was after.